# first lecture of AutowareAuto without point cloud and laser

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the first lecture of AutowareAuto, I tried to run 7 debugging commands in the ade environment according to the lecture notes.
But after I run the first 5 sentences, then  run: **ros2 run point_cloud_filter_transform_nodes point_cloud_filter_transform_node_exe...**
After that, point clouds still cannot appear on Rviz.

I see no error output, only after running the second sentence
**rviz2 -d /home/${USER}/autowareclass2020/code/src/01_DevelopmentEnvironment/aw_class2020.rvi**z, some warnings are displayed as follows:

*QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-gavinfang'

rviz2: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

rviz2: OpenGl version: 3.1 (GLSL 1.4)

rviz2: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

Parsing robot urdf xml string.

Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp

Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp

Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp

Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp

Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp*

I wonder if this affects point cloud generation? hi, everyone, can you help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389850/first-lecture-of-autowareauto-without-point-cloud-and-laser/) by [gavin fang](https://answers.ros.org/users/88044/gavin-fang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) on 2021-11-05**:
Could you add `autoware` tag to the question please for others to easily find this question?

**Comment by [gavin fang](https://answers.ros.org/users/88044/gavin-fang/) on 2021-11-05**:
Thanks and already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A recent version of `rviz2` on `foxy` had issues visualizing point clouds, you could try `sudo apt update ; sudo apt dist-upgrade` and rerun the command that opens up `rviz2` ?

---

Originally posted by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) with karma: 96 on 2021-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavin fang](https://answers.ros.org/users/88044/gavin-fang/) on 2021-11-05**:
Thanks a lot!
It's work now after update.
So it's not nvidia driver issue. and don't forget add /lidar_front/points_raw topic, thanks!

BR
Gavin Fang

**Comment by [xmfcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/46648/xmfcx/) on 2021-11-05**:
I'm glad it solved your problem! Could you mark this answer as correct with the tick symbol on the left? Thanks!